# EF Core for MySQL обрыв выполнения метода

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Есть у меня метод в репозитории, который обновляет объекты пачкой.

```
public Task UpdateRange(IEnumerable<AuthCode> authCodes)
{
   _context.AuthCodes.UpdateRange(authCodes);
   return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Проблема в том, что он отрабатывает лиш при первом обращении, при последующих обращениях поток выполнения доходит до строчки `_context.AuthCodes.UpdateRange(authCodes)` и обрывается, тем самым не выполняет команду сохранения изменений. Ошибки при этом ни какие не появляются.

Может кто-то подсказать что поисходит и как спарвить проблему.

Comment: Так у вас же рекурсия без возможности выхода, нет?

Comment: @Bulson c чего вы взяли что тут рекурсия?

Comment: `Task UpdateRange(IEnumerable<AuthCode> authCodes)` & `_context.AuthCodes.UpdateRange(authCodes);` как бы наводит на такие мысли.

Comment: @Bulson это обычный асинхронный метод, котоый певой строчкой отправляет в `ORM` обновленные объекты, потом отпавляет команду сохранить изменения.